# Isn't this wrong: if `all A are B` and `all B are C` then `some A are C`?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I found that statement on [Generalized Quantifier](https://plato.stanford.edu/archives/win2019/entries/generalized-quantifiers/#Aris) page of the Stanford Encyclopaedia of Philosophy.

```
all(A,B) # read all A are B
all(B,C)
-------- # therefore
some(A,C)
```

I'd expect the conclusion to be `all(A,C)`, but I'm also surprised that error went unnoticed since Winter 2019.

Can anyone confirm what's the correct one?

Comment: all(A,C) is correct. some(A,C) is incorrect. E.g. A: “is a six-legged chicken”, B: “is a chicken”, C: “is a bird”. All six-legged chickens are chickens, all chickens are birds, but none of the six-legged chickens are birds. (At least, I’ve never seen a six-legged chicken that is a bird. In fact, I’ve never seen a six-legged chicken, period.)

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but as mathematical statements this is correct (assuming $A\neq\emptyset$). I read this as $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$, therefore $A\cap C\neq\emptyset$ (again, assuming $A\neq\emptyset$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article is not in error. Please read the article carefully. It says that since Aristotle considered the syllogism

$$All \ A \ are \ B$$
$$All \ B \ are \ C$$
$$Some \ A \ are \ C$$

to be valid, he must have assumed that there is at least one $A$. Indeed, if there is at least one $A$, then the syllogism is valid.

More generally, within categorical logic (which is what Aristotle studied) the *Assumption of Categorical Existential Import* is the assumption that for any class (category) of things you talk about there is at least one representative. So *under that assumption*, the syllogism in the article is valid. Sometimes we say that this categorical syllogism is *conditionally valid*, as opposed to some other categorical syllogisms, which are unconditionally valid, i.e. do not need this extra Assumption. An obvious example of the latter is of course:

$$All \ A \ are \ B$$
$$All \ B \ are \ C$$
$$All \ A \ are \ C$$